# stackoverflow exception in simple mine sweeper game

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, stack-overflow

I am calling a recursive function (left click on the square) and I can’t find where the problem is.

It is supposed to change the background image to the correct number, set it to "pressed" and if it the number of mines near the square is 0, it will leftclick all the squares near it.

"board" is 2d array of squares(Mine class)

```
private void leftClick(int x, int y)
{
    if (!board[x][y].pressed)
    {
        if (board[x][y].bomb == true)
        {
            board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.bomb;
            if (MessageBox.Show("You lost! new game?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Form.ActiveForm.Hide();
                Form form2 = new MineSweeper.mainForm();
                form2.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
                Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            switch (board[x][y].numOfMines)
            {
                case 0:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._0;
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0 && x - 1 < row && y - 1 < column && board[x-1][y-1].pressed==false)
                        leftClick(x - 1, y - 1);
                    if (x >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0 && x < row && y - 1 < column && board[x][y - 1].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x, y - 1);
                    if (x + 1 >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0 && x + 1 < row && y - 1 < column && board[x + 1][y - 1].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x + 1, y - 1);
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && y >= 0 && x - 1 < row && y < column && board[x - 1][y].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x - 1, y);
                    if (x + 1 >= 0 && y >= 0 && x + 1 < row && y < column && board[x + 1][y].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x + 1, y);
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && y + 1 >= 0 && x - 1 < row && y + 1 < column && board[x - 1][y + 1].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x - 1, y + 1);
                    if (x >= 0 && y + 1 >= 0 && x < row && y + 1 < column && board[x ][y + 1].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x, y + 1);
                    if (x + 1 >= 0 && y + 1 >= 0 && x + 1 < row && y + 1 < column && board[x + 1][y + 1].pressed == false)
                        leftClick(x + 1, y + 1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    board[x][y].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._8;
                    break;
            }
        }
        board[x][y].pressed = true;
    }         
}
```

Comment: Rather than recursion, could you store all of the coordinates in a list and add to them and then process the list? That way you wont nest into recursion so much that you blow the stack.

Comment: I would consolidate all that bounds-checking logic--simply click the square whether or not it's on the board, have the click logic simply return if passed invalid coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Set `board[x][y].pressed = true;` before leftclicking the other mines. If you don't, the other mines might leftlick the original mine again.

```
if (!board[x][y].pressed)
{
    board[x][y].pressed = true;
    ... do the other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Something completely different: It is easier to create the board as a 2-D array in one bunch instead as of a jagged array and create the rows one by one. `Mine[,] board = new Mine[Width, Height];`. Then you can access the mines like this: `board[x, y].pressed = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the one that Olivier pointed out there's another recursion problem here that you haven't hit yet and almost certainly wouldn't in testing.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("You lost! new game?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Form.ActiveForm.Hide();
                Form form2 = new MineSweeper.mainForm();
                form2.ShowDialog();
            }
```

Rather than playing the game again in the same form you're creating a new form and **hiding** the old one.  While this recurses only one layer per game it's using up GDI resources (they are **not** anything like infinite, if you leak them it's easy to run out) and thus will blow if the user plays enough games.

Comment: you are right. how should i reload the form without leaking memory?

Comment: hmm ok i found solution..
i have made reset function so i stay in the same form.